# Go code "grep": show me all functions which return a struct called FooBar

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to search (aka "grep") some Go code, and show all functions/methods which return a struct called "FooBar"?

A command-line tool would be fine, or a way to do this in vscode.

In vscode, if I use "Go to References" I see the methods of this struct, too (which I don't want to see)

Update: I know how to use `grep` via the vscode terminal. But using `grep` or `rg` for this task is error-prone. I am looking for an AST-based solution.

Comment: There is a command line integration in vs code and thus you can use grep directly. Use aliases with excludes for .go files for example in order to achieve better results.

Comment: just use the Search bar and search for `FooBar` in `*.go` files, you get a few false positives, maybe search for `^\s*FooBar` to only get the cases where it is the first non-whitespace on a line

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [callgraph](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools@v0.5.0/cmd/callgraph#section-documentation) and `grep` combination to parse `go` code and find required returning value in functions signature.

**Install:**:

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/callgraph@latest
```

**Example:**

✳️ project structure

```
.
├── main.go
├── go.mod
├── service
│   └── service.go
└── types
    └── type.go
```

✳️ `service.go`

```
package service

import "github.com/some/project/types"

func ReturnX() types.X {
    return types.X{}
}

type Service struct {
}

func (Service) ReturnX() types.X {
    return types.X{}
}

func (Service) ReturnPtrX() *types.X {
    return &types.X{}
}
```

✳️ `type.go`

```
package types

type X struct {
}
```

✳️ `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/some/project/service"
)

func main() {
    A()
    s := service.Service{}

    s.ReturnX()
    s.ReturnPtrX()
}

func A() string {
    service.ReturnX()
    return ""
}
```

```
% callgraph -format '{{.Caller}}--{{.Dynamic}}-{{.Line}}:{{.Column}}-->{{.Callee}} - {{.Callee.Signature.Results}}}' main.go | grep types.X
command-line-arguments.A--static-16:17-->github.com/some/project/service.ReturnX - (github.com/some/project/types.X)}
command-line-arguments.main--static-11:11-->(github.com/some/project/service.Service).ReturnX - (github.com/some/project/types.X)}
command-line-arguments.main--static-12:14-->(github.com/some/project/service.Service).ReturnPtrX - (*github.com/some/project/types.X)}
```

to configure format look at the [source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/refs/tags/v0.5.0:cmd/callgraph/main.go). For example `.Callee` is [ssa.Function](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/ssa#Function) type -> you can use `text/template` syntax to reach it value (`{{.Callee.Signature.Results}}}`)

Comment: thank you very much `callgraph` looks like the right tool for this. It would be great to build a callgraphgrep tool with it.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:

- Loads the active directory.
- Skips any node that is not in the path:
  `Package > File > FuncDecl`
- Traverses the AST with DFS.
- Prints the names of found functions.
- Can work with variations of FooBar, such as `*FooBar, []FooBar, map[FooBar]any`...

```golang
func recursivelySearchForIdent(node ast.Node, identName string) bool {
    matchFound := false
    ast.Inspect(node, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        if n == nil {
            return false
        }
        if n, ok := n.(*ast.Ident); ok {
            if n.Name == identName {
                matchFound = true
            }
        }
        return true
    })
    return matchFound
}

func main() {
    packageName := "my_package"
    structName := "FooBar"

    pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(token.NewFileSet(), ".", nil, parser.AllErrors)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(errors.Wrap(err, "failed to load directory"))
    }

    if _, ok := pkgs[packageName]; !ok {
        log.Fatalln("failed to load package")
    }
    pkg := pkgs[packageName]

    selectedFuncDecls := []*ast.FuncDecl{}
    ast.Inspect(pkg, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        if n == nil {
            return false
        }

        switch n := n.(type) {
        case *ast.Package, *ast.File:
            return true
        case *ast.FuncDecl:
            if n.Type.Results != nil {
                if recursivelySearchForIdent(n.Type.Results, structName) {
                    selectedFuncDecls = append(selectedFuncDecls, n)
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    })
    for _, funcDecl := range selectedFuncDecls {
        fmt.Println(funcDecl.Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [ast-grep](https://ast-grep.github.io/) will be exactly the tool that can solve your question.
It is a command line tool to search code based on abstract syntax trees.

According to the [doc](https://ast-grep.github.io/guide/pattern-syntax.html), this query should match all Golang functions returning `FooBar`.

```golang
func $A($$$) *FooBar
```

Explanation:

- This is a function declaration to match any function that returns a pointer of `FooBar`.
- `$A` after `func` represents a wildcard that matches any name.
- `$$$` is like a `*` repetition symbol to match zero or more AST nodes. It can match any function regardless of its parameters.

See the online [playground example](https://ast-grep.github.io/playground.html#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)

If you also need to match method syntax, I think a YAML can help you.

```yaml
rule:
  any:
    - pattern: func $A($$$) *FooBar
    - pattern: func ($S $TYPE) $M($$$) *FooBar
```

[Playground demo](https://ast-grep.github.io/playground.html#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)